# Параллельные запросы OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Возможно ли параллельная запись с помощью oledb в excel? Создаются несколько потоков, в каждом выполняется update одного документа. Будут  ли они записывать данные независимо друг от друга или же, все-таки, последовательно?

Comment: параллельная запись в файл навряд ли получится. Скорее всего вы не спожете писать разными писателями сразу, а один писатель будет работать в один поток. Как же это рулит сама библиотека oledb - я не в курсе.

Comment: Пока вы не откажетесь от экселя, вас будут преследовать то тут, то там всякие ограничения. Используйте нормальную базу данных для записи.

Comment: @aepot, был бы я против использования другой Б)). Обстоятельства(

Comment: Ну тогда могу только посочувствовать.